# How to use numpad / on a keyboard without a numpad?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, shortcut

I've just got into Blender, and I like it a lot. But as I just switched from a stationary computer to a MacBook, I've got some new problems regarding the numpad. I can use 1-9 perfectly, But I have no idea how to emulate buttons like <kbd>/</kbd> (used to enter local view). I've searched the web for an answer, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 27):

When [*Emulate numpad*](http://blender.org/manual/preferences/input.html?highlight=emulate%20numpad#numpad-emulation) is enabled in *User preferences > Input*, <kbd>\</kbd> (often the key below the <kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd> key) will act as <kbd>numpad /</kbd>.

**Blender 2.8x**

[image]

**Blender 2.7x**

[image]

*Emulate numpad* will also make the number row above the main keyboard act like the numbers on the numpad.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for how to replace numpad with other shortcuts in blender (I want to buy a keyboard without numpad) and found this question, so it may be the best place to write it for others looking for the same thing.

With newer releases of Blender, there is an addon called Pie Menus Official. After enabling it in User Preferences, pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> will display a menu with some options.

I preferred this instead of *Emulate Numpad* because it keeps the layers shortcuts in the same place.

[image: Q Pie Menu]

When you select `More` or press <kbd>3</kbd> it will bring another menu with the remaining operations:

[image]

in Version > 3.5 this pie Menu is much improved:

To enable "Pie Menu" in Add-ons go to *Preferences  > Add-ons* and search for `pie`

Enable Pie Menus *Interface: 3D Viewport Pie Menus*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of Blender 2.80rc1 you can use the <kbd>`</kbd> key much like the pie menu from Pie Menus Official. The <kbd>/</kbd> switches to and from local view even with emulate numpad disabled.
[image: pie menu screenshot]

Comment: FYI, seems to be keyboard dependent, The key is 'ù' on azerty keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**For Laptops without Numpad**

**Pie Menu** seems to be a Better option:

***Versions > 3.5***

```
To enable the Pie Menu add-on:

Preferences   ->
  Add-ons        ->
    (Search) pie  ->
     Enable Pie Menus  ->
       ✅ Interface: 3D Viewport Pie Menus
```

[image]