# How do I get my file to export as a .stl?

Tags: modeling

I can't export my object as an .stl.  I started with a UV Sphere and I used a boolean modifier on it and joined other objects to it. I removed doubles, re-calculated normals, tried triangulation, selected the object when exporting. Nothing works and the .stl file is empty. I also uploaded it to https://netfabb.azurewebsites.net/ and it was rejected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty vague and hard to help with provided information. Give us some more info, post some images of your model or screenshots of your modifier stack or ideally post your Blend file if possible.

Comment: what happens if you export the default cube of the startup scene?

Comment: I'm a novice just starting last week on it, so sorry for being vague.

Comment: I uploaded the file here: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1155" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1155/)

Answer (score 1):

The Local View is enabled for this object in your file.

[image: object screenshot]

> Local view isolates the selected object or objects, so that they are the only ones visible in the viewport.

*[manual page](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#local-view)*

Press <kbd>NumpadSlash</kbd> to exit it, select the object and try exporting again.

*A side note*:
- although you recalculated normals some of them are still inverted (the bottom);
- the topology of the mesh is a bit off, especially on the bottom, which can cause unexpected results when triangulated.
- scale of the mesh isn't applied (which can also be undesired);
However, this doesn't affect your current problem directly.

Comment: I know I got a long way to go and I'll have to read up on your comments.  I'm on a Mac so not sure what the NumpadSlash equivalent is so I'll look that up too. Thanks for taking a look. You guys are great.

Comment: @Zowee see [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16308/how-to-use-numpad-on-a-keyboard-without-a-numpad), could be useful. In general you can remap shortcuts to new ones in order to use them as desired. As for my recommendations, the only thing that should be done is exiting from the Local View. The last paragraph doesn't affect this and was mentioned only for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Create a new default start-up Blender file. Append your sphere from your original file into this new Blender file. When it is appended (so you can see it in your new Blender scene), select it and export it as an stl. Does that  work for you?  It did for me... this is what I get:

EDIT:
Sorry... wrong link: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxiyub2pu6i10c3/untitled.stl?dl=0
END EDIT

Let me know...

If you need info on appending: https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html

Comment: This seemed to work as the file size seems normal. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks... and see Mr Zak's answer below for some notes on the mesh... and esp. applying scale. Out of curiosity, what are you printing it on? We're getting a new Form 2 in a couple of weeks... and like using Blender for STLs. If you have a copy of ZBrush, it's really handy for hollowing out shells, however.. it's something that ZB does a little better than Blender...