# Is it okay to use Blender with a non-numpad laptop?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

Currently, the problem is not the rendering, but more on modelling, shortcut, etc. I have a laptop with no numpad. Most YouTube tutorials use numpad for view and others shortcut. Sure, I could make the numbers area being opt to numpad mode, but it'll restrict other feature. Is it still okay to continue without any numpad configuration?

Comment: yes, the numpad is mostly used to change the view, but you can assign that to the other number keys

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16308/how-to-use-numpad-on-a-keyboard-without-a-numpad/16309#16309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily replace numpad numbers by just clicking on circles in the Navigation Gizmo:

[image]

Other than that, you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for a command, and if you use it often, you can $\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right-click* on a command and *Assign Shortcut*.

Comment: I'm fine with the view stuffs. But I just want to make sure if there are no other core modelling features that requires numpad.